# Insert date in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date

When i executed the below query in Oracle

```
select TO_CHAR((CURRENT_DATE),'DD-Mon-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')  from dual;
 O/P : 04-Mar-2014 14:25:14
```

I would like to select `current date` only without `current time` as below

```
select TO_CHAR(trunc(CURRENT_DATE),'DD-Mon-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')  from dual;
O/P  :  04-Mar-2014 00:00:00
```

To achieve the only way is to apply function `trunc()` on the query? Is there any another way?

**Edit :** Thanks for your ans.Can it be done without any function?(wihout using to_char or trunc)
{sorry for missing this info}

Comment: Can someone explain me why i received downvotes for this question.Is it a trivial question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is simply **no**, there is no function that only gets the date part of the date / time (even `current_date` or `sysdate` are functions after all).

You should always use `trunc` to get the current date, without the time.

It isn't necessary to do a `trunc` and a `to_char` together. Keep `to_char` and don't specify the time part.

This is sufficient:

To get the date as `varchar`:

```
select TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE,'DD-Mon-YYYY')  from dual
```

To get the date as `date`, with the time part as `00:00:00`:

```
select trunc(CURRENT_DATE)  from dual
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
select TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE,'DD-Mon-YYYY')||' 00:00:00'  from dual;
```

Comment: that's not, what OP asked

Answer (score 1):

there is also EXTRACT function which can be used like that:

```
SELECT extract(DAY FROM sysdate)
||'-' ||
extract(MONTH FROM sysdate) 
|| '-' || extract(YEAR FROM sysdate) 
FROM dual;
```

result: 4-3-2014

Answer (score -1):

Use This Query...

```
select (TO_CHAR(TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE),'DD-Mon-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))  from dual
```

Comment: How is that different from what was shown in the question, apart from the extra and unnecessary set of parentheses?